# Why CGI.pm does not handle UTF-8 properly when dealing with "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forms?

Tags: perl, utf-8, cgi

I upgraded yesterday Debian stable and with "new" Perl 5.14 i got "new" CGI module as well (v3.52). Previous version was 3.43, i think. Upgrade broke my old webforms and i figured out that UTF-8 chars from fields of forms with enctype "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" get decoded twice. While with enctype "multipart/form-data" everything works fine.

Question:

- Why UTF-8 in forms with "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" are not handled properly? They should still decoded correctly, even when "multipart/form-data" may be better for handling binary data.

Here is little testcase which addresses decoding problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8::all;
use CGI qw(:all -utf8);

my $q = new CGI;

sub build_form {
  return q|
  <form method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
  <br />
  Y: <input type="text" name="y" />
  </form>|;
}

print $q->header( -type=>"text/html; charset=utf-8", ),
  $q->start_html( -title=>"test", -encoding=>"utf-8" ),
  $q->h1(  $q->param(  'x' ) . " " ),
  $q->start_form(),
  "X: ",
  $q->textfield( -name=>'x' ), 
  $q->end_form(), "\n\n", 
  $q->br(),
  $q->h1( $q->param( 'y' ) . " " ),
  build_form(),
  $q->end_html;
```

PS. I don't think that upgrade broke UTF-8 decoding. Seems like after upgrade automatically generated forms were with wrong enctype ("application/x-www-form-urlencoded") because using deprecated helper methods (e.g `startform` instead `start_form`).

Comment: Define "not handled properly"? Your script works fine for me.

Comment: @ikegami: if i enter 'õ' to the both form fields, submitting X gives me back 'õ', Y gives 'Ãµ'. Last one is result of double decoding, AFAIU.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
use utf8::all;
```

does

```
binmode(STDIN, ':encoding(UTF-8)');
```

which corrupts the data sent by the browser. Follow up with

```
binmode(STDIN);
```

to undo the change and prevent the damage.

Comment: Do you have an explanation, why one form enctype is affected and other not?

Comment: Because õ appears as its UTF-8 encoding when the decoding occurs for one and as its URI encoding for the other.